# elasticsearch response parsing error in profile daata

Tags: java, elasticsearch, objectmapper

I am using 7.4 ElasticSearchClient and querying to Elasticsearch.
I am getting response in profile object like below

```
"profile": {
"shards": [
{
"id": "[GArOi1iwQHGY2qpSalRgHw][hbs-search-3][0]",
"searches": [
{
"query": ["rewrite_time": 2061901,
"collector": [
{
"name": "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
"reason": "search_top_hits",
"time_in_nanos": 30527860
}
]
}
],
"aggregations": ,
"fetch": {
"type": "fetch",
"description": "",
"time_in_nanos": 2716234862,
"breakdown": {
"load_stored_fields": 4382099,
"load_source": 13298,
"load_stored_fields_count": 50,
"next_reader_count": 8,
"load_source_count": 50,
"next_reader": 96419
},
"debug": {
"stored_fields": [
"_id",
"_routing",
"_source"
]
},
"children": [
{
"type": "ExplainPhase",
"description": "",
"time_in_nanos": 2487325658,
"breakdown": {
"process_count": 50,
"process": 2487313600,
```

and using co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.SearchResponse class from java service to get parsed response but as in abouve response value "process": 2487313600 is out of bound for int value as SearchResponse class has variable for same is of type int

```
@Nullable
private final Integer process;
```

i tried doing parser changes at get client level

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS, true);
            JacksonJsonpMapper jacksonJsonpMapper= new JacksonJsonpMapper(mapper);
            
            ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, jacksonJsonpMapper);
            ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
            success = true;
            return client;
```

any thing need to add to get that value as long or profile time in millis